# Testing Slack bots built with Bolt SDK

Tags: java, testing, slack, slack-api

I'm building a Java slack bot using the bolt-java-sdk.

The application is working fine however I would like to add tests to verify everything works before pushing to production.

The SDK is not quite clear enough for me to figure out a way to set up the tests, for example to send a slash command event to the application and then confirming the correct response is returned.

Can anyone please help me out?